# How to get shaded background in xyplot in R?

Tags: r, background, lattice, color-scheme, figure

using `xyplot` from the `lattice` package, I plot a time series over a number of years. I would to add a shaded area for some of these years to indicate that this time period was "special" (e.g. war).

Please apologize if this is trivial, but I could not figure out how to do that, so I would be happy if someone could help me out, or at least point me in the right direction. I think my main problem is that I don't really know how to approach this problem. I am still relatively new to R, and to `lattice` in particular.

Here a minimal example:

```
 xyplot( rnorm(100) ~ 1:100, type="l", col="black")
```

In the corresponding plot, I would like the color of the background (from say `x`-values of 45 until 65) from the bottom to the top of the plotting area be shaded in, say, light grey.

Note that solutions that I have found so far use `base` graphics and the `polygon`-function, but there the intention is to shade the area under or above a curve, which is different from what I would like to do. I don't "just" want to shade the area below my line, or above my line. Instead I would like to shade the entire background for a given time interval.

If anyone could help me out here, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `?panel.xblocks` in the latticeExtra package:

```
library(latticeExtra)
x <- 1:100
xyplot( rnorm(100) ~ x, type="l", col="black") + 
         layer_(panel.xblocks(x, x > 20, col = "lightgrey"))
```

[image]

Comment: Appears rather powerful.  `y=x > 45 & y <0` gets you grey bands to the left of x=45, but only where y<0.  I think you chose to use `layer_` because it has a default of `under=TRUE`?

Comment: It just seemed rather nifty and ggplot2-ish but alternately one could use it in a conventional panel function: `xyplot( rnorm(100) ~ x, type="l", col="black", panel = function(x, ...) {         panel.xblocks(x, x > 20, col = "lightgrey"); panel.xyplot(x, ...) })` .

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 xyplot( 
    rnorm(100) ~ 1:100, type="l", col="black",
    panel=function (x,y,...){
    panel.rect(xleft=45, xright=65,ybottom=-3, ytop=3,col="grey")
    panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
    }
  )
```

The `panel.rect()` function controls the rectangle and is the lattice equivalent of the `rect()` function. It has a variety of settings that you may find useful. It is called first and then the `xyplot()` is put on top of it. You many need to play around a little to get your `ybottom` and `ytop` parameters to look as you like them.

Comment: Wow, thanks guys, that was quick. Your solutions definitely help me. They also teach me some new things, which is why I love this website! I hope at some point in time I will be proficient enough so as to contribute here myself! Thanks and have a good weekend!

Answer (score 3):

```
trellis.focus("panel", 1, 1)
grid.rect(x =.55, , y=.5, w = .2, height=6,  
  gp = gpar(fill = "light grey"))
trellis.unfocus()
```

This differs from @JohnPaul's solution in a couple of ways (and I think his answer is better). This uses the center of the desired X-band for placement in "native coordinates" and calculates the width as 'range(xlim)/range(band)' and it modifies an existing plot. the `grid.rect` function is the grid packages lower level function that is used by `panel.rect`. I sometimes find this useful when integrating lattice panels inside the `xyplot` system defeats me.